# Sort a queryset in a particular situation - Django

Tags: django

I've this model:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Titolo')
    text = models.TextField(verbose_name='Testo')
    category = TreeForeignKey(CoursesCategory, verbose_name='Categoria')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and i've another model in another app:

```
class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    value = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Voto')
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_pk = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_pk')
```

Now, I should order, in the Question view, the questions queryset whit the relative value of Model Like.

I'm trying to use this method

```
def get_queryset(self):
    questions = Question.objects.all()
    questions = questions.annotate(ranking_vote=Coalesce(Sum(...), 0)).order_by('-ranking_vote')
```

but I can not figure out what the solution.

Can you help me..

Comment: I don't understand your problem: whether your problem with how to use get_queryset() or whether your problem with how to write a sorting queryset. Could you make your problem definition and question more precise?

Comment: You can't access to Like with your Question model. You need to create a link between yours models.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question) # New field
    value = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Voto')
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_pk = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_pk')
```

After this you can use : `like_set` on Question object.

```
q.like_set.count() # return like number link to this question object
```

About your request you can do :

```
from django.db.models import Count
questions = Question.objects.annotate(num_like=Count('like')).order_by('-num_like')
```